# Where do I find my app_id, app_secret and page-access-token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

We cannot find anywhere in the developer area the `app_id`, `app_secret` and `page-access-token`.

We are trying to pull our marketing data programatically with a Python script, to then export it as a CSV or write it to a DB. This is the code snippet that I copied directly from [the official GitHub page](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages') # Replace this with the place you installed facebookads using pip
sys.path.append('/opt/homebrew/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebook_business-3.0.0-py2.7.egg-info') # same as above

from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount

my_app_id = 'your-app-id'
my_app_secret = 'your-appsecret'
my_access_token = 'your-page-access-token'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)
my_account = AdAccount('act\_\<your-adaccount-id\>')
campaigns = my_account.get_campaigns()
```

It works, in the sense that it connects to the API, but we simply cannot find these three properties:

```
my_app_id = 'your-app-id'
my_app_secret = 'your-appsecret'
my_access_token = 'your-page-access-token'
```

At this point, I'm starting to suspect that they first need to be generated and that we somehow don't have them even though we already have marketing data in there.

So, where exactly can we find them, either programatically or graphically through the website?

Comment: You find app id and app secret in your app dashboard. If you have already created an app, that is ...

Comment: And a page access token is something you need to _create_. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens